# C++ calls default constructor instead of copy constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I'm trying to write a program for my Arduino, but I don't understand something that's happening when passing an `Item` object to another `Holder` object. I've constructed a simple example:

```
class Item {
  public:
    int property;

    Item() {
      Serial.println("parameterless constructor called");
      this->property = 2;
    }

    Item(int property) {
      this->property = property;
      Serial.println("right constructor called");
    }
};

class Holder {
  public:
    Item someitem;

    Holder(Item& someitem) {
      this->someitem = someitem;
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Item someitem = Item(1);
  Serial.println(someitem.property);

  Holder hold = Holder(someitem);
  Serial.println(hold.someitem.property);
}

void loop() {

}
```

The output on the console is:

```
right constructor called
1
parameterless constructor called
1
```

I don't understand why the parameterless constructor is called in the first place (I'm not creating a new object to my understanding), and also why it does neither change the current object nor makes a new one. Leaving out the parameterless constructor is prevented by the compiler.

Comment: You should have fixed the errors given by the compiler when you have "Leaving out the parameterless constructor is prevented by the compiler."

Comment: @DieterLücking He did, but the wrong way :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You forgot how we initialize class members in C++ - [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Holder(Item const& someitem) : someitem(someitem) {}
```

In your code, `someitem` is default-constructed first (before execution enters the `{}` block of the constructor), then you're using assignment operator.

Copy constructor is not invoked (and it can't be on already constructed object).

Comment: Thanks! This works, and pointed me to further reading. I'm still thinking too much in java it seems...